# Data-binding arguments of a function with AngularJS in ng-click

Tags: angularjs, function, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am using ng-click to call a function with arguments I get from the $scope. Unfortunately either are the arguments not processed from angular or I get this error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [:notification] starting at [:notification].

HTML snippet that results in error:

```
<div ng-click="goToNotif({{notification.id}})"></div>
```

HTML snippet not being processed from angular:

```
<div ng-click="goToNotif(notification.id)"></div>
```

IMPORTANT: `notification` is parsed from a repeat

```
<div(ng-repeat="notification in notifications")></div>
```

Comment: the second one should definitely work ..make sure you defined goToNotif as $scope.goToNotif=function(){}

Comment: don't use expression syntax `{{ }}`for arguments of a scoped function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the code for index.html, define "notifications" seperately -

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div(ng-repeat="notification in notifications")>
        <div ng-click="go(notification.id)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In main.js -

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.go = function() {
//write code here.
}
});
```

Comment: I was trying to do this inside a directive template and everything else uses the binding syntax ( {{id}} ).....EXCEPT this part - was banging my head on the desk......thanks!